# Controls Handle

Tags: c#

how to get a handle of a particular control from a exe and set that handle to a control present in another exe?

Answer (score 1):

var controlHandle = YourControl.Handle.ToInt32();

Then you can use your favorite inter process communication method e.g. remoting to send that int to another process..